# MySQL takes over 1 second to do a simple query sometimes

Tags: mysql

My `MySQL` server is processing about 180 queries per second, the vast majority of which are very fast. However, about 1 in 1,000 queries takes over a second and I can't work out why.

e.g.

```
SHOW tables FROM mydbname LIKE 'tablename'
```

took 1.00054. If I re-run that query manually it takes 10ms.

In a sample of 55,000 queries, 44 took over 1 second then the next slowest was 0.28. There are no long `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries. Server load is less than 1. Memory is not being swapped.

How do I track down this annoying problem? It's make my web pages get served up too slowly.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?  Or MyISAM?

Comment: Is the "slow" query early after restarting mysqld?  If so, it is a caching issue.

Comment: What query types?  You show a `SHOW`.  Are you referring to `SELECTs`, too?

Comment: Hi Rick - InnoDB. There's no difference after a restart. 99% of all queries are SELECTs

Comment: Are you doing all the work in a single PHP occurrence?  Or is it like a web server, wherein each request fires up a new PHP occurrence?  (This question has been prompted by gmw's Answer.)

Comment: It's my own web server so there are multiple PHP instances

Comment: Does one of those `SELECTs` scan a big table?  Bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  What is the setting of that?  How much RAM do you have?  What version of MySQL?  For deeper analysis:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: The ones that are delayed are a mixture - some are very simple and others do bigger scans. 4Gb RAM.   ``innodb_buffer_pool_size`` is 134217728  and 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1  I have a table that is 1.6 Gib. All the queries I am referring to use indexes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what client language you are using, but it could be the garbage collector kicking in. Once every 1,000 requests doesn't sound unreasonable for garbage collection to make itself known.

In Java, this can probably be tuned a bit using one of the parallel garbage collectors available (don't know which one though, been a while since I messed with Java).

Comment: Thanks - I'm using this: PHP Version => 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7

Comment: Ok – I don't know much about PHP, but a quick Google for "php garbage collection" indicates that garbage collection has been improved in PHP 7.3. See https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/what-is-garbage-collection-in-php-and-how-do-you-make-the-most-of-it

Answer (score 0):

- 4GB of RAM is small these days.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be 600M if the server is primarily for MariaDB.
- A scan of "a table that is 1.6 Gib" will blow out the buffer_pool, leading to sluggishness of anything else running at the same time.  Even an index scan may blow out the cache.
- "All the queries I am referring to use indexes" - But are they optimal.  (Many programmers don't yet understand the beauty of a carefully selected 'composite' index.)
- Is the machine swapping any?  (That could lead to serious slowdowns.)
- `SHOW TABLES` requires a lot of file-system I/O (in 10.1).
- Can you provide another sample of the 44 queries slower than 1s.